# make checks with class and stop the script

Tags: php

I created a script to change the user's password, but when checking it continues.

```
class mudar_senha{

    protected $page_return = 'mudar_senha';

    private function encriptaSenha($senha) {    

            return base64_encode(pack("H*", sha1(utf8_encode($senha))));
    }

    private function query_senha(){

        global $_LANG;

            $user_id = $_POST['id_user'];

            $q=new Query;
            $q
                    ->select()
                    ->from('`usuarios`')
                    ->where_equal_to(
                            array(
                                    'id'=>$user_id
                            )
                    )
                    ->limit(1)
                    ->run();

            if($q){
                    $user=$q->get_selected();

                    return $user['senha'];
            }
            else{


            return 
                alerta($_LANG[165]);
                retornar(NULL,$this->page_return);  
                    die;    
            }       
    }

    private function verify_senha($senha){

        global $_LANG;

            if($this->encriptaSenha($senha) == $this->query_senha()){

                return true;    

            }else{


                return 
                    alerta($_LANG[203]);
                    retornar(NULL,$this->page_return);  
                    die;    
            }

    }

    private function verify_senhas(){

        global $_LANG;

            if($_POST['cpass1'] == $_POST['pass1']){

                return true;

            }else{

                return 
                    alerta($_LANG[171]);
                    retornar(NULL,$this->page_return);  
                    die;
            }


    }

    private function verify_length($senha){

        global $_LANG;

            switch($senha){

                case(strlen($senha) < 6) :

                    return $_LANG[206];
                        die;

                case(strlen($senha) > 11):

                return 
                    alerta($_LANG[205]);
                    retornar(NULL,$this->page_return);  
                    die;

                default:

                    return true;
            }

    }

    private function verify_caracteres($senha){

        global $_LANG;

            if(preg_match('/[\'\/~`\!@#\$%\^&\*\(\)_\-\+=\{\}\[\]\|;:"\<\>,\.\?\\\]/', $senha)){

                return 
                        alerta($_LANG[204]);
                        retornar(NULL,$this->page_return);  
                        exit;
            }else{

                return true;

            }

    }

    final public function _build(){

        global $_LANG;

            if($this->verify_senha($_POST['req1'])      == true);
            if($this->verify_senhas()                   == true);
            if($this->verify_length($_POST['pass1'])    == true);
            if($this->verify_caracteres($_POST['pass1'])== true);

                $q=new Query;
                $q
                    ->update('usuarios')
                    ->set(
                            array(
                                            'senha'         =>  $this->encriptaSenha($_POST['pass1']),
                                            'pass_decode'   =>  $_POST['pass1'],
                            )
                    )
                    ->where_equal_to(
                            array(
                                    'id'=>$_POST['id_user']
                            )
                    )

                    ->limit(1)
                    ->run();

                        if($q){

                            alerta($_LANG[207]);
                            retornar(NULL,$this->page_return);

                        }else{

                            alerta($_LANG[165]);
                            retornar(NULL,$this->page_return);
                            exit;
                        }       
    }


}


$q = new mudar_senha;
$q->_build();
```

there are only three checks
- Correct password?
- Correct passwords?
- Password length
- Special characters

if it denies the checks the script returns true, and it does _build function checks if changes continue normally.

Comment: And what exactly is your question? I see code, what it does and how it processes... But no question, no fault, no error code

Comment: Anything that comes after a `return` statement is ignored. That is how return statements work. PHP ought to display an `E_NOTICE` or `E_STRICT` for stuff like this, but for some reason it is just ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of your `die;` statements are after your `return` statements. If you're going to kill the script, remove the `return` statement beforehand since the value won't matter anyway.